# Allocating Memory In A Function To Return to User

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I have a function which sends a command over serial, then receives a response of unknown size.  Using

```
(ioctl(fd_, FIONREAD, &bytes_in_buffer);
```

I determine how much memory I need to allocate for my read.

```
//This code calls the function below
unsigned char CheckRefresh[] = {254, 124, 0};
unsigned char * response;
unsigned int size;
relay_board->SendCustomCommand(CheckRefresh, 3, &response, size);

ErrorCode SendCustomCommand(unsigned char * command, unsigned int command_size, unsigned char **response, unsigned int &response_size)
{
  //Send the command
  write(fd_, command, command_size);

  // ... Omitting Polling Code to Get correct number of bytes ...
  (ioctl(fd_, FIONREAD, &bytes_in_buffer);

  //Now getting the response
  response_size = (unsigned int)bytes_in_buffer;
  (*response) = new unsigned char(response_size);
  if(read(fd_, *response, response_size) < 0)
  {
    std::cout << "[ProXRSerial] SendCustomCommand: Read failed... -- Errno: " << errno << std::endl;
    return Failed;
  };
  return Success;
}
```

I believe this is corrupting my stack, as my next function call breaks at

```
unsigned char * command = new unsigned char(3);
```

with the following:

```
sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -
__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) 
(old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 
* (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && 
((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

Could anyone offer some advice?  I am at a loss, I thought passing the double pointer like that would allow me to allocate memory for the user...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
(*response) = new unsigned char(response_size);
```

should read

```
(*response) = new unsigned char[response_size];
```

Your version allocates *one* unsigned character, and initializes it with the value `response_size`.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you so much.  The funny thing is so far all my other codes been working, doing the same thing, yet accessing and writing way out of its bounds... oh heap.

Comment: `response = new unsigned char[responze_size];`

Comment: same goes for `unsigned char *command = new unsigned char(3);`, no?

Comment: @jrok: No, `response` if of type `unsigned char**`, not of type `unsigned char*`. It's an output parameter in C style.

Comment: My bad, I only noticed the `response` declaration in 3rd line (that one is unsigned char*)

Comment: Wait, celtschk so only because I ma dealing with a `*(unsigned char **)` that this problem occurs?  My other allocation is fine?  So `unsigned char * test = new unsigned char(27)` is correct?

Comment: @jpm: Yes. And possibly a few other calls to `new` elsewhere in the code as well.

Comment: @Constantin: No, my comment was directed to jrok who incorrectly suggested two comments before that the result to `new` should be assigned to `response` instead of `(*response)`. Your problem is not related to the type of `response` (that part you did right). Always when you want to allocate an array, you need to use the `[]` syntax (and remember to delete with `delete[]`). Of course, probably a better solution would be to use `vector` and forget about manual memory management.

Comment: Thank you so much, and yes I adjusted my deletes [] right away.  After I read your comment it all came rushing back at me.